# Is the Laplace transform a linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, laplace-transform, signal-processing

Many sources online states that the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}: V \to W,  f(t) \mapsto F(s)$ is a linear operator

For example:

1. [http://www2.fiu.edu/~aladrog/PropLaplaceTransform.pdf](http://www2.fiu.edu/%7Ealadrog/PropLaplaceTransform.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2017*/http://www2.fiu.edu/%7Ealadrog/PropLaplaceTransform.pdf))
2. http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ME401-1.2.2-LaplaceTransform.pdf

However, closely examining the definition of linear operator on Wikipedia, it says:

> In mathematics, a linear map (also called a linear mapping, linear
> transformation or, in some contexts, linear function) is a mapping V →
> W between two modules (including vector spaces) that preserves (in the
> sense defined below) the operations of addition and scalar
> multiplication.
>
> An **important special case** is when V = W, in which case the map is
> called a **linear operator**,[1] or an endomorphism of V.

Do we know that the Laplace transform is a endomorphism? It doesn't seem plausible given that we are taking a function in time domain, say $L_2[0, \infty)$ space, and mapping it into $H_2$ space

So should the Laplace transform be a linear operator?

Comment: Definition of Laplace transform involves integral, so yes.

Comment: As usually defined, domain and range of the Laplace transformation are different spaces (one _can_ consider it on a space $V$ so that $\mathcal{L}(V) \subset V$ and thus have an endomorphism, but that'd be unusual). But not everybody reserves the term "operator" for endomorphisms, lots of people call also linear maps between different spaces operator.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, why not leave it as an answer

Comment: You're right, why not? Moving it into an answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is usually defined, the domain and range of the Laplace transformation are different spaces. The domain is usually a space of measurable functions defined on $[0,+\infty)$, and the range a space of holomorphic functions. One can however choose a space $V$ as the domain such that $\mathcal{L}(V) \subset V$ [for example the space of bounded holomorphic functions defined on the right half-plane], and then one can view $\mathcal{L}$ as an endomorphism of $V$.

But the main source of calling the Laplace transformation a linear operator is that not all people reserve the term "operator" for endomorphisms, many people call any [or possibly only continuous or closed] linear maps "operator". With that convention, the Laplace transformation is a linear operator in the more common settings.